# Highcharts Area Range charts zooming and tooltip queries

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am trying to get a few things done in the high charts area range chart:

1. I am trying to be able to zoom into the chart mainly y axis and I am unable to do that can someone suggest me how that can be achieved I am adding the jsfiddle link below with the sample code where I am trying to add the zoom.
2. For the tooltip of the same chart I am trying to get the value of the point as well as the range values for the same point when I hover over it. Also I don't want any tooltip when I hover on the range.
   i.e. if I hover over the point for AAL 1A Nov'22 3311.6781801806596 in the tooltip I am expecting to see

**AAL_1A: 3311.6781801806596
AAL_1A 95 range: 3066.798502204227, 3556.557858157093**

but what I have written with that I don't see any tooltip to be generated, can someone help me on how to get what I am expecting

JS Fiddle:

`code`[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/fgzLw90y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

1. In the case of zoom, use `chart.zooming` option. You can choose the type of zooming - `x`, `y` or `xy`.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.zooming
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.zooming.type

2. When It comes to tooltip, you need to set `enableMouseTracking: false` for each `arearange` series type and improve the formatting function.

   ```
    tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      const {
        series,
        x,
        y
      } = this;
      let text = '';
      series.chart.series.forEach(series => {
        if (this.series.options.name === series.name) {
          text += `<span style=\"color:${this.color}\">●</span> ${series.name}: <b>${this.y}</b><br/>`
        } else if (this.series.options.name === series.options.linkedTo) {
          series.points.forEach(point => {
            if (x === point.x && point.options.high) {
              text += `<span style=\"color:${point.color}\">●</span> ${series.name}: <b>${point.low}</b> - <b>${point.high}</b><br/>`
            }
          })
        }
      })
      return text
    }
   ```

   },

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zumfjth2/